# Python numerical data processing

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame that is all numeric and contains some error values such as :**10..9,10...9** etc. I want to keep only one decimal place. What do I do with that?

Comment: You round to one decimal place.  This is easy to look up.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

**Example data:**

```
values = ['10.9', '10..9', '10...9']
```

**Using `re`:**

```
list(map(lambda x: float(re.sub('\.+', '.', x)), values))
[10.9, 10.9, 10.9]
```

**Using `pandas`:**

```
s = pd.Series(values)
s.str.replace('\.+', '.').astype(float)

0    10.9
1    10.9
2    10.9
dtype: float64
```

Comment: The data in your example is not numeric.

Comment: Yes, because there're no numbers with two points in Python, like the user provided. I assumed the OP actually have strings and would like to to strip off additional points (in order to make them numeric).

Comment: That's the reason, I think, the user maked `re` in the tags. But I might be wrong.